# XBEE to XBEE - Sending multiple chars from one to another

Tags: xbee

I am trying to get one Xbee to send to another Xbee. I am using the Xbees on FRDM-K64Fs. The following works but only for a single char:

Receiver code

```
if(xbee.readable()){
    char x = xbee.getc();
    if(x == 'W'){      
       lcd.locate (1, 1);
       lcd.printf("Received Char");
    }
    wait(1);
}
```

Sender code:

```
xbee.putc('W');
wait(0.5);
```

The problem is when I try to execute `xbee.putc` multiple times because still only one char is received. I need a way to send a string or an int(longer than one digit).

I have tried using `xbee.printf` in my sending code and using `while(xbee.readable())` in my receiving code which doesn't seem to work either.

Is there a method which I should use?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you update your receiver code to repeatedly check for characters?  Just replace the `if(xbee.readable())` with `while (xbee.readable())`.